# Add header to a domain

Tags: dns, http-headers

I have a situation where a (potentially) large number of domains will be pointing to my MVC application. Now I need to authenticate these domains to decide if I serve the request or not, I could put all of these domains in a SQL table and do a lookup each time a request comes in (which will work but I don't think this is optimal) or I could hopefully configure each of these domains to include a token of some sort in their header so I can authenticate against this instead.

I don't own these domains, so is there anyway I can ask the domain owners to configure their domain to include an additional header, and the value of that header will be a token which I provide them?

Comment: I don't understand. The domain owners originate HTTP connections to their own domains? If not, how can they be expected to set any headers in HTTP connections to the domain?

Comment: sorry it must be my lack of knowledge in the area, yes I am after a configuration on the domain owners end to always provide a token when sending the request. it doesn't matter how this is accomplished (http header or otherwise)

Comment: If the domain owners are sending requests then I guess you can ask them to add a custom header to their HTTP requests (perhaps via a browser extension if they are using regular browsers?) or use a proxy server that does it for them, but this is still not making sense to me.

Comment: Ok I guess it is not possible, I guess I will have to do a lookup :(

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use cloudflare to apply configurations on domain level.